# React - Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm fairly new to React.  I am working on a note app and when I add 2 notes, they have the same key and the next 2 notes also share their own key and so on.  I started off with prop drilling from the App to the AddNote file via NotesList.js and it was working fine and the problem has only occurred since I used useContext API so maybe I am not coding the useContext in the correct way.  The useContext component looks like this:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const HandleAddContext = createContext();
export default HandleAddContext;
```

This is my App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

import NotesList from "./components/NotesList";
import HandleAddContext from "./components/UseContext/HandleAddContext";

const unique_id = uuid();
const small_id = unique_id.slice(0, 8);

const initialState = [
  {
    id: small_id,
    text: "1st note",
    date: "12/10/22022",
  },
  {
    id: small_id,
    text: "2nd note",
    date: "15/10/22022",
  },
  {
    id: small_id,
    text: "3rd note",
    date: "16/10/22022",
  },
  {
    id: small_id,
    text: "4th note",
    date: "30/10/22022",
  },
];

export const App = () => {
  const [notes, setNote] = useState(initialState);

  const addHandleNote = (text) => {
    console.log(text);
    const date = new Date();
    const newNote = {
      id: small_id,
      text: text,
      date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
    };

    console.log(newNote);
    const newNotes = [...notes, newNote];
    setNote(newNotes);
  };

  return (
    <HandleAddContext.Provider value={addHandleNote}>
      <div className="container">
        <NotesList notes={notes} />
      </div>
    </HandleAddContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is the component with map notes

```
import Note from "./Note";
import AddNote from "./AddNote";

const NotesList = ({ notes }) => {
  return (
    <div className="notes-list">
      {notes.map((note) => (
        <Note key={note.id}  id={note.id} text={note.text} date={note.date} />
      ))}
      <AddNote />
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotesList;
```

This is the Note:

```
import { RiDeleteBin6Line } from "react-icons/ri";

const Note = ({ text, date }) => {
  return (
    <div className="note">
      {/* <div> */}
      <p>{text}</p>
      {/* </div> */}
      <div className="note-footer">
        <p className="note-footer-text">{date}</p>
        <RiDeleteBin6Line />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Note;
```

This is the AddNote.js component

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { RiSave2Line } from "react-icons/ri";

const AddNote = ({ handleAddNote }) => {
  const [addText, setAddText] = useState("");
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");

  //handle text input
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setAddText(e.target.value);
  };

  //handle save
  const handleSaveClick = () => {
    if (addText.trim().length > 0) {
      handleAddNote(addText);
    }  
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        rows="8"
        cols="10"
        placeholder="Type here to add a note..."
        value={addText}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <div>
        <p>200 characters remaining</p>
        <RiSave2Line onClick={handleSaveClick} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddNote;
```

Comment: all ids are the same using the `small_id`

Comment: you created the `small_id` only once and used it everywhere, so all the ids are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your `unique_id` and `small_id` are only being generated once due to your function call syntax.

`const unique_id = uuid();`

Assigns `unique_id` the result of `uuid()`, rather than referencing the function. And therefore `small_id` is simply slicing the already generated `uuid`. To fix this your must generate a new uuid every time you create a note. Your can create a **function** that return a new 'small ID' everytime.

```
function genSmallID() {
 return uuid().slice(0, 8);
}
```

And now when you create your initial notes use the function:

```
const initialState = [{
    id: genSmallID(),
    text: "1st note",
    date: "12/10/22022",
  }, {
    id: genSmallID(),
    text: "2nd note",
    date: "15/10/22022",
  }, {
    id: genSmallID(),
    text: "3rd note",
    date: "16/10/22022",
  }, {
    id: genSmallID(),
    text: "4th note",
    date: "30/10/22022",
}];
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that I was just referencing one uuid rather than calling a function that generated a new uuid.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NS No worries, if my solution worked for you please could you give it a tick and upvote :)

Comment: I've added a tick, but cannot cast a vote as I don't have enough reputation. :)

Answer (score 0):

by setting a variable

> const small_id = unique_id.slice(0, 8);

you create a variable and assign it to each element of your `initialState` array's id.
you should delete `small_id` and `unique_id` and do this:

```js
const initialState = [{
    id: uuid().slice(0, 8),
    text: "1st note",
    date: "12/10/22022",
  }, {
    id: uuid().slice(0, 8),
    text: "2nd note",
    date: "15/10/22022",
  }, {
    id: uuid().slice(0, 8),
    text: "3rd note",
    date: "16/10/22022",
  }, {
    id: uuid().slice(0, 8),
    text: "4th note",
    date: "30/10/22022",
}];
```

In order to have different id (here you have always the same), or if the id isn't relevant for you you can always use the element's position in the array as `key` with the 2nd parameter of the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
<div className="notes-list">
  {notes.map((note, key) => (
    <Note key={key}  id={note.id} text={note.text} date={note.date} />
  ))}
<AddNote />
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked for me, although I ended up using the solution Jack Ecuyer posted.  However I did use the `key={key}` , which I hadn't seen before.